# How to catch Marz/März/M&auml;rz?

Tags: php, html, regex, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to find the month in a text written in German. (In an html file)

March is written "März".

I want to be sure that I catch it so I check

Marz,
März,
M&auml;rz

I tried to use this code

```
if(preg_match("/ma?ä?(&auml;)?rz/i", $title))
    return 3;
```

It works fine for the first two, but doesn't with &auml;.
What did I do wrong ?

(The HTML and my PHP files are encoded in UTF8)

Comment: What about M&#228;rz? :)

Comment: Maybe you should also look for something like `[0-3]?[0-9]\. ?[0-1]?[0-9]\.` (numeric representation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just try

```
(Marz|März|M&auml;rz)
```

Comment: @Keng: Did you forget a semicolom?

Comment: @Keng: No, it's part of a html entity: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/#

Comment: Ok thx it works like that!
But I still don't understand why my way didn't.

Comment: What about "Maerz"?  That’s also legal.  And is "ä" really code point U+E4, or is it code points U+61 and U+306? You must deal with both. If you run it through one of the [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/), probably NFD or NFC, this becomes someone easier. But not using Unicode collator objects is a **complete lose!**

Comment: @NeqO look at thejh's answer. he may have the solution for 'why' it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first decode the entities, then use a comparison that works with the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/). For example, this works in Perl:

```
use Unicode::Collate;

my $Collator = Unicode::Collate->new(normalization => undef, level => 1);
my $str = "Ich muß Perl studieren.";
my $sub = "MÜSS";
my $match;
if (my($pos,$len) = $Collator->index($str, $sub)) {
    $match = substr($str, $pos, $len);
}
```

Matching things with and without marks is possible according to what `level` of comparison you wish done.

How you perform basic Unicode operations like this in PHP I do not know, but I figure there must be a corresponding library, given how necessary these types of things are.

Answer (score 2):

`ä` is more than one byte or something like that - you have to do this:

```
preg_match("/ma?(ä)?(&auml;)?rz/i", $title);
```

[You can see it here](http://ideone.com/Fc58b).

Besides, Kengs approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for searching purposes but *not* for returning the actual position of the word, you could normalize the search string using `html_entity_decode()` and `iconv()`:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);

// then search for "Marz"
```

Comment: Ug, that’s horrible: you mutilate the data! ☹ You have to work *with* Unicode, not against it!

Comment: @tchrist so what if a copy of the data is mutilated? Unfortunately, I do not know of a PHP library that does what your suggestion does in Perl.

Comment: @tchrist only very patchily. There's nothing like `Unicode::Collate` in standard PHP as far as I know. Maybe in PHP 6 (sigh)

Comment: @Pekka: Well, that makes it tough.  Is there a module for `Unicode::Normalize` at least?

Comment: @tchrist I think there is a PEAR module but also not in the standard library. This is a much lamented shortcoming of PHP, and the fact that the development of Version 6 seems to have come to a halt for the time being is not helping

Comment: @Pekka, that’s really a shame. Unicode is critical in any 21ˢᵗ century text handling, and that means more than UTF-8; it also means support for the various algorithms and properties that Unicode defines. I imagine that as a native German speaker, you brush up against this more often than most monoglot anglophones. Are their non-English speakers in the core PHP development team? Did you know that Perl’s `Unicode::Collate::Locale` module supports a "de__phonebook" locale? I image you know what that’s for.  Now if only it had an "en__phonebook" locale. ☹

Comment: @tchrist yeah! Unicode is damn important. At least mySQL can deal with it properly, that takes a lot of the pain away... Having that sort of functionality natively in the programming language would be really nice. The phonebook locale treats Umlauts `äöü`  equal to `ae  oe ue` instead of as their normalized versions `a o u`. This  is also the way Umlauts are ordered in the english language, which is why there is no `en_phonebook`. How and why this phonebook sorting came about in the first place I have no idea... Finnish, swedish and austrian german have *again* different sorting rules.

Comment: @Pekka: We need `en_phonebook` for named starting with `Mc` or `Mac`, the old patronymic.  Correct sorting is that all surnames with either prefix are (1) sorted together without regard to which of the two spellings is used and (2) go at the front of the M’s, before any other Ma names.

Comment: @tchrist ahh, very interesting! I didn't know english had such cases. I have a lot of respect for the people working on libraries in the character set and date/time areas. There's such a *shitload* of (sometimes constantly changing) specifics you need to be aware of

Comment: @Pekka: Yep, your better bookstores and libraries always use “English phonebook sorting” when arranging books by author.  The thing is that you actually have to stem the [Scots surname](http://www.electricscotland.com/webclans/septs.htm), because it *only* counts if it’s an old patronymic, like in *MᶜKinley, Macallen, MacDonald, MᶜEwan, MacTaggart, MacBride, MᶜCartney, MᶜKellan, Macalroy, MᶜVeigh, Macintosh, Mackichan, Macbeth, Macduff,* etc., and not if it just happens, like in *Macaroni, Macey, Macau, Machiavelli, Mackinac, Machete, Machine, Mackerel, Macrame, Macusi,* etc.

Comment: @tchrist Ohhh boy! That is *so* interesting. If I had loads of money and didn't have to work, I'd go and study english linguistics and history. I guess that list you link to is the reason why there is no `en__phonebook`?

Comment: @Pekka: That may well be why there isn’t one; me, I dunno. It reminds me of the problem of capitalizing book, song, and movie titles (etc) in English. Unless they occur as the first or last word, you do not capitalize articles *(a, an, the)* or short prepositions. Problem is that it takes a real parse to distinguish prepositions from adverbs used in phrasal verbs. For example, these are both correct as titles: *Bringing **In** the Sheaves* with a phrasal verb but *Ringing **in** the Ears* with a preposition. It’s a bit like dative-vs-accusative for prepositions after motion verbs in German.

Comment: @tchrist that goes to show that there's a *lot* more to  "internationalization" than the tiny fraction we programmers deal with every day. Thanks for the outlook!